# Items are not added to list (of T)

Tags: vb.net

I have created a few classes for Actor, location and object.
Class Location:

```
Public Class AdvLocation

Private m_Name As String
Private m_NameAlias As String
Private m_Description As String
Private m_Dark As Byte '0=Dark,
Private m_ExitN As String
Private m_ExitNE As String
Private m_ExitE As String
Private m_ExitSE As String
Private m_ExitS As String
Private m_ExitSW As String
Private m_ExitW As String
Private m_ExitNW As String
Private m_ExitUp As String
Private m_ExitDown As String
Private m_ExitIn As String
Private m_ExitOut As String
Private m_ExitNHidden As Boolean
Private m_ExitNEHidden As Boolean
Private m_ExitEHidden As Boolean
Private m_ExitSEHidden As Boolean
Private m_ExitSHidden As Boolean
Private m_ExitSWHidden As Boolean
Private m_ExitWHidden As Boolean
Private m_ExitNWHidden As Boolean
Private m_ExitUpHidden As Boolean
Private m_ExitDownHidden As Boolean
Private m_ExitInHidden As Boolean
Private m_ExitOutHidden As Boolean
Private m_ExitNLockObj As String
Private m_ExitNELockObj As String
Private m_ExitELockObj As String
Private m_ExitSELockObj As String
Private m_ExitSLockObj As String
Private m_ExitSWLockObj As String
Private m_ExitWLockObj As String
Private m_ExitNWLockObj As String
Private m_ExitUpLockObj As String
Private m_ExitDownLockObj As String
Private m_ExitInLockObj As String
Private m_ExitOutLockObj As String

Public Property Name As String
    Get
        Return m_Name
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_Name = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property NameAlias As String
    Get
        Return m_NameAlias
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_NameAlias = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Description As String
    Get
        Return m_Description
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_Description = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Dark As Boolean
    Get
        Return m_Dark
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        m_Dark = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ExitN As String
    Get
        Return m_ExitN
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_ExitN = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ExitNE As String
    Get
        Return m_ExitNE
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_ExitNE = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ExitE As String
    Get
        Return m_ExitE
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_ExitE = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ExitSE As String
    Get
        Return m_ExitSE
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_ExitSE = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ExitS As String
    Get
        Return m_ExitS
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_ExitS = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ExitSW As String
    Get
        Return m_ExitSW
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_ExitSW = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ExitW As String
    Get
        Return m_ExitW
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_ExitW = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ExitNW As String
    Get
        Return m_ExitNW
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_ExitNW = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ExitUp As String
    Get
        Return m_ExitUp
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_ExitUp = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ExitDown As String
    Get
        Return m_ExitDown
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_ExitDown = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ExitIn As String
    Get
        Return m_ExitIn
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_ExitIn = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ExitOut As String
    Get
        Return m_ExitOut
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_ExitOut = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ExitNHidden As Boolean
    Get
        Return m_ExitNHidden
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        m_ExitNHidden = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ExitNEHidden As Boolean
    Get
        Return m_ExitNEHidden
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        m_ExitNEHidden = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ExitEHidden As Boolean
    Get
        Return m_ExitEHidden
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        m_ExitE = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ExitSEHidden As Boolean
    Get
        Return m_ExitSEHidden
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        m_ExitSE = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ExitSHidden As Boolean
    Get
        Return m_ExitSHidden
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        m_ExitSHidden = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ExitSWHidden As Boolean
    Get
        Return m_ExitSWHidden
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        m_ExitSWHidden = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ExitWHidden As Boolean
    Get
        Return m_ExitWHidden
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        m_ExitWHidden = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ExitNWHidden As Boolean
    Get
        Return m_ExitNWHidden
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        m_ExitNWHidden = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ExitUpHidden As Boolean
    Get
        Return m_ExitUpHidden
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        m_ExitUpHidden = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ExitDownHidden As Boolean
    Get
        Return m_ExitDownHidden
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        m_ExitDownHidden = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ExitInHidden As Boolean
    Get
        Return m_ExitInHidden
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        m_ExitInHidden = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ExitOutHidden As Boolean
    Get
        Return m_ExitOutHidden
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        m_ExitOutHidden = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ExitNLockObj As String
    Get
        Return m_ExitNLockObj
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_ExitNLockObj = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ExitNELockObj As String
    Get
        Return m_ExitNELockObj
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_ExitNELockObj = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ExitELockObj As String
    Get
        Return m_ExitELockObj
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_ExitELockObj = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ExitSELockObj As String
    Get
        Return m_ExitSELockObj
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_ExitSELockObj = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ExitSLockObj As String
    Get
        Return m_ExitSLockObj
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_ExitSLockObj = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ExitSWLockObj As String
    Get
        Return m_ExitSWLockObj
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_ExitSWLockObj = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ExitWLockObj As String
    Get
        Return m_ExitWLockObj
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_ExitWLockObj = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property ExitNWLockObj As String
    Get
        Return m_ExitNWLockObj
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_ExitNWLockObj = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ExitUpLockObj As String
    Get
        Return m_ExitUpLockObj
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_ExitUpLockObj = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ExitDownLockObj As String
    Get
        Return m_ExitDownLockObj
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_ExitDownLockObj = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ExitInLockObj As String
    Get
        Return m_ExitInLockObj
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_ExitInLockObj = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ExitOutLockObj As String
    Get
        Return m_ExitOutLockObj
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_ExitOutLockObj = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub New(ByVal m_Name As String,
               ByVal m_NameAlias As String,
               ByVal m_Description As String,
               ByVal m_Dark As Boolean,
               ByVal m_ExitN As String,
               ByVal m_ExitNE As String,
               ByVal m_ExitE As String,
               ByVal m_ExitSE As String,
               ByVal m_ExitS As String,
               ByVal m_ExitSW As String,
               ByVal m_ExitW As String,
               ByVal m_ExitNW As String,
               ByVal m_ExitUp As String,
               ByVal m_ExitDown As String,
               ByVal m_ExitIn As String,
               ByVal m_ExitOut As String,
               ByVal m_ExitNHidden As Boolean,
               ByVal m_ExitNEHidden As Boolean,
               ByVal m_ExitEHidden As Boolean,
               ByVal m_ExitSEHidden As Boolean,
               ByVal m_ExitSHidden As Boolean,
               ByVal m_ExitSWHidden As Boolean,
               ByVal m_ExitWHidden As Boolean,
               ByVal m_ExitNWHidden As Boolean,
               ByVal m_ExitUpHidden As Boolean,
               ByVal m_ExitDownHidden As Boolean,
               ByVal m_ExitInHidden As Boolean,
               ByVal m_ExitOutHidden As Boolean,
               ByVal m_ExitNLockObj As String,
               ByVal m_ExitNELockObj As String,
               ByVal m_ExitELockObj As String,
               ByVal m_ExitSELockObj As String,
               ByVal m_ExitSLockObj As String,
               ByVal m_ExitSWLockObj As String,
               ByVal m_ExitWLockObj As String,
               ByVal m_ExitNWLockObj As String,
               ByVal m_ExitUpLockObj As String,
               ByVal m_ExitDownLockObj As String,
               ByVal m_ExitInLockObj As String,
               ByVal m_ExitOutLockObj As String)
    Name = m_Name
    NameAlias = m_NameAlias
    Description = m_Description
    Dark = m_Dark
    ExitN = m_ExitN
    ExitNE = m_ExitNE
    ExitE = m_ExitE
    ExitSE = m_ExitSE
    ExitS = m_ExitS
    ExitSW = m_ExitSW
    ExitW = m_ExitW
    ExitNW = m_ExitNW
    ExitUp = m_ExitUp
    ExitDown = m_ExitDown
    ExitIn = m_ExitIn
    ExitOut = m_ExitOut
    ExitNHidden = m_ExitNHidden
    ExitNEHidden = m_ExitNEHidden
    ExitEHidden = m_ExitEHidden
    ExitSEHidden = m_ExitSEHidden
    ExitSHidden = m_ExitSHidden
    ExitSWHidden = m_ExitSWHidden
    ExitWHidden = m_ExitWHidden
    ExitNWHidden = m_ExitNWHidden
    ExitUpHidden = m_ExitUpHidden
    ExitDownHidden = m_ExitDownHidden
    ExitInHidden = m_ExitInHidden
    ExitOutHidden = m_ExitOutHidden
    ExitNLockObj = m_ExitNLockObj
    ExitNELockObj = m_ExitNELockObj
    ExitELockObj = m_ExitELockObj
    ExitSELockObj = m_ExitSELockObj
    ExitSLockObj = m_ExitSLockObj
    ExitSWLockObj = m_ExitSWLockObj
    ExitWLockObj = m_ExitWLockObj
    ExitNWLockObj = m_ExitNWLockObj

End Sub

End Class
```

In the main form the List (of T) is declared:

```
Public Class frmMain

'Declare variables and lists
Public Shared lngScore As Long = 0
Public Shared MaxScore = 100
Public Shared strScreen As String = ""
Public Shared blnSave As Boolean = True
Public Shared strCurLocation As String
Public Shared Locations As New List(Of AdvLocation)
Public Shared Actors As New List(Of AdvActor)
Public Shared Objs As New List(Of AdvObject)
```

In the sub InitLoc Locations will be added to the list:

```
    'Locations
Public Sub InitLoc()

    Locations.Add(New AdvLocation("doorstep1", "Cindy's house", "You are in front of your girlfriends house.", False, _
                         "hallway1", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", _
                         False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, _
                         "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""))
    Locations.Add(New AdvLocation("hallway1", "Hallway", "You are standing in the hallway.", False, _
                         "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", _
                         False, False, False, False, "doorstep1", False, False, False, False, False, False, False, _
                         "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""))

End Sub
```

And here comes the problem: The first location is added to the list as it should, but the second one is not added nor is the first one overwritten. I don't get any errors too, either it does not execute the 2nd add or it generates an error which is not displayed.

The code should be correct, but maybe it's not.
To be complete, there are no error traps yet.
I hope someone can help me.

Comment: There have been auto implemented properties in VB for several years now.  It would reduce all that boilerplate code dramatically.

Comment: I get an error at runtime that doorstop1 isn't a boolean on the second.

Comment: I just changed it, now it works, strange thing though that I don't get any error.

Comment: Turn on Option Strict - you are passing all string in the constructor but it is written for some of them to be bools

Comment: I also changed the classes for auto implemented properties. Thanks for your comments. It's an old source from VB6 which I have to update.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you don't declare the variables as Public Property instead of all the methods at the bottom. The get and set methods are included in the property data type.

Second, you could create two arrays to hold these objects to avoid the lists.

I am guessing that along the way, the variables or types are being mixed up. Turning option strict on like plutonix said should reveal any issues.